# Why is there no DbSet.ToIEnumerableAsync()

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

To make sure I understand this correctly, if I have the following:

```cs
    DbContext context;
    DbSet<User> Users;
    
    // This line creates an Expression object, but there is no call to the database
    var expr = context.Users.Select().Where().OrderBy();
```

Now if I need to get an enumeration of what is returned by that expression, then I call:

```cs
    // this will kick off a query against the DB.
    var list = await context.Users.Select().Where().OrderBy().ToListAsync();
```

Now the above code is starting a query and returning to allow the code to continue while the query completes. Now if what I want is a list, this is perfect.

But here's my question. If all I need is an IEnumerable, then I would use ToIEnumerableAsync() instead of ToListAsync(). Except that does not exist. **Why?** Is it that for an async query it needs something explicit to load the returned data into?

And an associated question. I can write the following:

```cs
foreach (var item in context.Users.Select().Where().OrderBy())
```

This works because an Expression implements IEnumerable. To confirm, in this case, when the foreach starts executing, it calls Enumerable() on that expression and at that point, it now makes a synchronous call to the DB - correct?

This is not a problem or even an issue for my programming. But I'm curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF Core supports `IAsyncEnumerable` if you want to stream the results rather than materialize the set in memory with `ToListAsync` or `ToArrayAsync`.

```
var list = (IAsyncEnumerable<User>) context.Users.Select().Where().OrderBy();
```

From there you can iterate over the results:

```
await foreach(var user in list)
{
    ...
}
```

or `yield` results from a query without first loading them into memory. This does appear to have some limitations in EF if handing off to some streaming providers where the recommendation is to ensure that lazy loading is not enabled if using async enumerators.